# Using big-O to prove N^2 is O(2^N)

Tags: big-o, proof

I can clearly see than N^2 is bounded by c2^N, but how do i prove it by using formal definition of big-O. I can simply prove it by M.I.

Here is my attempt..
By definition, there for any n>n0, there exist a constant C which 
    f(n) <= Cg(n) 
where 
    f(n) = n^2 
and 
    g(n) = 2^n

Should I take log to both side and solve for C?

and one more question about fibonacci sequence, i wanna solve the recurrence relation.

```
int fib(int n){
   if(n<=1) return n;
   else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
```

The equation is..

```
T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)+C // where c is for the adding operation
```

so

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + 2T(n-3) + T(n-4) + 3c
```

and one more

```
T(n) = T(n-3) + 3T(n-4) + 3T(n-5) + T(n-6) + 6c
```

then i started to get lost to form the general equation i 
The pattern is somehow like pascal triangle?

```
 t(n) = t(n-i) + aT(n-i-1) + bT(n-i-2) + ... + kT(n-i-i) + C
```

Comment: Better ask [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: o.. so should i del the post here?

Comment: one way is to use a limit as n approaches infinity of g(n)/f(n)

Comment: Would you mind explain a bit more in detail? 2^n / n^2 as 2^n grow faster than n^2, when n tends to infintiy g(n)/f(n) will tends to infinity as well, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you point out, to see if *f(x) ϵ O(g(x))* you need to find...

- ...some *c > 0* and
- ...some *x<sub>0</sub>*

such that *f(x) < c·g(x)* for all *x > x<sub>0</sub>*.

In this case, you can pick *c = 1* and *x<sub>0</sub> = 2*. What you need to prove is that

*x<sup>2</sup> < 2<sup>x</sup>* for all *x > 2*

At this point you can log both sides (since if log(*x*) > log(*y*), then *x > y*.) Assuming you're using base-2 log you get the following

*log(x<sup>2</sup>) < log(2<sup>x</sup>)*

and by standard laws of logarithms, you get

*2·log(x) < x·log(2)*

Since *log(2) = 1* this can be written as

*2·log(x) < x*

If we set *x* = 2, we get

*2·log(2)* = 2

and since *x* grows faster than *log(x)* we know that *2·log(x) < x* holds for all *x > 2*.

Comment: Because for *x* = 2 we have 2 * log(2) = 2 ≤ 2 and log(x) grows faster than *x*.

Comment: But "log(x) grows faster than x" is the statement we want to prove right? We wanted to prove "2^N grows faster than N^2".

Comment: (First of all, sorry that should have been "x grows faster than log(x)" in my last comment.) Anyway, I think you can take that fact for granted.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, the accepted answer (from aioobe) is correct, but there is an important correction that needs to be made.

Yes, for x=2, *2×log(x) = x* or *2×log(2) = 2* is correct, but then he incorrectly implies that *2×log(x) < x* is true for ALL x>2, which is not true.

Let's take x=3, so the equation becomes: *2×log(3) < 3* (an invalid equation).

If you calculate this, you get: *2×log(3) ≈ 3,16993*  which is greater than 3.

You can clearly see this if you plot *f(x) =  x<sup>2</sup>* and *g(x) = 2<sup>x</sup>* or if you plot *f(x)= 2×log(x)* and *g(x) = x* (if c=1).

[image: f(x)=x2 and g(x) =2n plotted]

Between x=2 and x=4, you can see that g(x) will dip below f(x). It is only when x **≥** 4, that f(x) will remain **≤** c×g(x).

So to get the correct answer, you follow the steps described in aioobe's answer, but you plot the functions to get the **last** intersection where *f(x) = c×g(x)*. The x at that intersection is your x<sub>0</sub> (together with the choosen c) for which the following is true: *f(x) **≤** c×g(x)* for all *x **≥** x<sub>0</sub>*.

So for c=1 it should be: for all x≥4, or x<sub>0</sub>=4

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon the accepted answer:

You have to prove that x^2 < 2^x for all x > 2

Taking log on both sides, we have to prove that:
2·log(x) < x for all x > 2

Thus we have to show the function h(x)=x-2·log(x)>0 for all x>2

h(2)=0

Differentiating h(x) with respect to x, we get h'(x)= 1 - 1/(x·ln(2))

For all x>2, h'(x) is always greater than 0, thus h(x) keeps increasing and since h(2)=0, 
it is hence proved that h(x) > 0 for all x > 2,
or x^2 < 2^x for all x > 2